# Two Dimensional Python Array: Sort second by First

Tags: python

I have a Multidimensional array in Python.

How do I go about sorting the second array, by the first - all the while keeping it in the same order?

Comment: can you provide an example? what do you mean sorting the second by the first and keeping the same order?

Comment: I'm unclear exactly how you want your array(s) sorted.  Can you edit your question to provide a simple before/after example of what your array looks like before and after being sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from your answer if this is what you want, but take a look and see. If I have a multidimensional array x:

```
>>> x = [[100,50,39,69,22,23,19,80,94,72],range(10)]
>>> print x
[[100, 50, 39, 69, 22, 23, 19, 80, 94, 72], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

and I want to sort the second subarray by the first subarray, I could do the following:

```
>>> x[1].sort(key = x[0].__getitem__)
>>> print x
[[100, 50, 39, 69, 22, 23, 19, 80, 94, 72], [6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 9, 7, 8, 0]]
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of order this is sorting against?

Comment: It's like the 0 in the second array is has a value of 100 attached to it that is its 'sort value or key' and 1 in the second array has 50 as its sort value and so forth (2 has sort value 39, 3 has sort value 69). I'm sorting the second array by the values of the first array. That was my guess as to what the OP was asking.